# Issue With Xamarin.Forms Images in iOS Renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I hope someone can help me with this weird problem.

I'm in Xamarin Forms, in a renderer. I'm passing a `Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource` into a `ImageLoaderSourceHandler`.

```
var_imageLoader = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
```

However, when I `await` the `LoadImageAsync` method it always returns null, rather than `UIimage`.

```
if (_view.Icon?.Source != null)
{
    _iconImageView.Image = 
        await _imageLoader.LoadImageAsync(_view.Icon.Source);
}
```

My images are in the `Resource` directory and are `BundleResource`as build action.

The file naming is correct (menu.png, menu@2x.png, menu@3x.png) and I've run out if ideas.

Anyone got a clue or two ?
Thanks

Comment: Dean, can you show the code instead of describing it?

Comment: Its a large amount of code, so I've just added the relevant bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageLoaderSourceHandler` is used if you want to download images from a Url.

Since your files are local you need to use `FileImageSourceHandler`

You can use this help method to get you the right type.

```
private static IImageSourceHandler GetHandler(ImageSource source)
        {
            IImageSourceHandler returnValue = null;
            if (source is UriImageSource)
            {
                returnValue = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
            }
            else if (source is FileImageSource)
            {
                returnValue = new FileImageSourceHandler();
            }
            else if (source is StreamImageSource)
            {
                returnValue = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
```